# Error writing to SQL Database when user leaves field blank

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a windows form that the user will fill out whenever we add a new employee. If I fill in the form completely, I can write to the database, but if one field gets left blank, I get an error. In the SQL table, all rows are set to allow nulls, and I can insert via SQL Server Management Studio with null values with no problems.

For brevity, I have left off a dozen or so fields, but the same error occurs if I replace this code with the code I am using.

```
Dim DBConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Try
WOWConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=MyServerName;Database=Employee Database;Trusted_Connection=TRUE;"
WOWConnection.Open()
cmd.Connection = WOWConnection
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees]([FirstName],[LastName]) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Me.EMP_FirstName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Me.EMP_LastName.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Sucess!")
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("error")
Finally
DBConnection.Close()
End Try
```

How do you handle a field being left blank on a windows form?

Comment: what's the actual error?

Comment: It's hitting my exception and popping up my "error" message box. I do not see an actual error. The debugger returns this:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x994) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1094) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7356] HR.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Chnage your catch handler to display the exception!

Comment: Change `MsgBox("error")` with `MsgBox(ex.Message)`

Comment: I can't see anything intrinsically wrong with your code. Are there database constraints that prevent empty name fields?

Comment: OK, I set the message to display the exception. (Thank you Marco for the code, and Mitch for the suggestion) and the error is: The query expects the parameter '@State', which was not supplied. (Again, I shortened the code above)

@State is handled by: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", Me.EMP_State.SelectedValue)

In SSMS, I checked the  properties of the 'State' column, and 'Allow Nulls' is set to 'Yes'. (As are all of the columns currently, I set them all to allow for testing.)

Comment: I checked my oOnLoad for the form, and I had set my selected index to -1 to prevent a default selection.

I changed that and the error changed to "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric." After testing, I find that if my phone number fields are left blank (@HomePhone, and @CellPhone), then the script will fail. The phone numbers are stored in SQL as decimal(10,0).

Comment: After some poking around, I came up with the following solution:

    If Me.EMP_CellPhone.Text = "" Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhone", DBNull.Value)
    Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhone", Me.EMP_CellPhone.Text)
    End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the value being inserted before passing the value to SQL.
Note that NULL value and Empty is not the same in SQL.

> cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].Employees VALUES 
>     (@FirstName,@LastName)"
>
> If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.EMP_FirstName.Text) Then
>
> ```
>       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Me.EMP_FirstName.Text)
> ```
>
> Else
>
> ```
>       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", DBNull.Value)
> ```
>
> EndIf
>
> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()